# Discharging high voltage and capacitance capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, high-voltage

I need to discharge a 4.4mF (millifarads) capacitor storing 1200V in about 5 seconds. I did the `t=R*C`' and got a resistance value of approximately 227ohms. I did a calculation for the energy in the capacitor `E=1/2*C*V^2` and got out 3168J. I had a look online at resistors and they either have the power or voltage but not both. They are also rather large and I'm hoping to keep it as small as possible so my overall project isn't too big. Is there a way of connecting the resistors in parallel or series that might achieve the power and voltage requirements without damaging the resistors?

Side note: I had a look online at the parallel and series connections but I'm not quite sure if you still need to voltage rating or power rating to be high enough or do they add together?

Comment: *I did a calculation for the power in the capacitor 'E=1/2*C*V^2' and got out 3168J* Watch your units! Power is Joule/second, you calculated the **energy** in the capacitor. Releasing that in 5 seconds gives how many Watt? Note that 3000 J released in 1 second is 3000 W, that's a lot of power. Spreading it over 5 seconds loweres it to 600W, still a lot of power.

Comment: You could use a long, thick, insulated cable to short the capacitor to ground. With sufficient length, the inductance of the cable will keep the current from rising too quickly, and the low resistance will ensure the capacitor is actually discharged. It will be an exciting experience though ;-) First try with lower voltages and monitor currents and temperatures, then extrapolate to high voltage.

Comment: Remember to use an insulated boom / handle to touch cable to the capacitor, not your hand... Also leave the two connected long enough, the voltage will still need to decay.

Comment: Don't you have supervisors when playing with these power levels? You could easily get killed...

Comment: Do you actually mean 4.4 millifarads?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusion I caused. I fixed the question. @pipe yeah sorry. I meant discharge. Decharge is just a habit I picked up from a lecturer. The actual resistance value that I got was 227ohms, I just confused it with another value when typing it in.

Comment: @ EvertW I have supervisors (I'm just on placement from college). I amn't actually going near these voltages at any point right now. I'm just trying to figure out ideas on how to accomplish this before presenting it to them to see what they want to go with. I'm just looking for a little help in understanding it.

Comment: @Finbarr yeah. Sorry.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie sorry, I got confused when doing the calculations. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I'd be tempted to dump this energy into a liter of salty water, using 2 copper plates on opposite sides of 0.1meter cube. Vary the amount of salt, to fine tune the discharge rate. Note the probable production of various gases as the heat and electrolysis take hold of the water/salt. Chlorine is one of the gases. I wonder if your supervisors are testing you, to see if you have any sense of impending danger?

Comment: I would probably do this with a current sink using SiC FETs.

Comment: Agreeing with @PeterSmith because if you use your 227-ohm concept, you will still have 37% of the voltage (440V) on the capacitor after 5 seconds.  What you need is a FET or FETs capable of handling 600 watts and controlled so that they run at constant power (current must increase as voltage drops).

Comment: @PeterSmith - how would you go about doing that? sorry I tried looking into it but I don't really know anything about FETs or IGBT. Even if there was just a source of information ye can point me to that would be amazing! Thank you by the way.

Comment: sorry I couldn't add @JohnBirckhead in the previous comment.

Comment: @Student : the design and implementation of such a circuit is not trivial. I came up with a concept for it last night in about an hour, but the details would probably take me several hours and then significant simulation and analysis time. Due to the voltage and power involved, significant safety precautions are required so I would suggest that this is a bit beyond you at present.

Comment: Once again I agree with @PeterSmith and must warn you that this is a potentially dangerous capacitor charge, possibly even lethal.  Also, wear safety glasses - I have had switching FETS fail and hot pieces fly off.   However, if you don't want to to do an intricate circuit design, I would suggest that you place a number of high-wattage (I would try 200W) incandescent bulbs in series so that their combined voltage would equal 1200 V.  In the US, you would need 10. When the current drops and the filaments cool, the resistance will also drop so you will discharge faster.  PLEASE BE CAREFUL!

Comment: @JohnBirckhead will do. I'll have a look into the FETS and the bulbs. Thank you for helping. I'll be careful. I'm not going to be implementing any of these anytime soon and they'll be going through skilled professionals before I'm allowed near them. I'm just simply looking for ideas at the moment is all. Can I just quickly ask (I haven't looked into this an awful lot yet) would a gas discharge tube be of any use or would it be too dangerous?

Comment: Not sure about gas discharge tubes but maybe someone else can comment.